# How can I SELECT based upon a user-input variable?

Tags: sql, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to build a `SELECT` statement allowing users to have control over whether the results will be consolidated down into one row or split by a variable. Essentially, I want the user to be able to dynamically add or remove one or more fields by using a dropdown with two options.

The logic is quite straightforward but I have no idea how to parse it. I think it should be something like the below for the 'split' options:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN $userchoice='split' THEN field1, field2, approx_distinct(stuff)
```

versus something like this for the combined option:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN $userchoice='combined' THEN approx_distinct(stuff)
```

I am failing with:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN ${splitorconsolidate=consolidate|split}='split'
        THEN    field1, field2, approx_distinct(stuff) as total_stuff
    ELSE approx_distinct(stuff) as total_stuff
END;
```

getting the error `mismatched input ','. Expecting: 'WHEN', <expression>`

Is this possible? This is via Zeppelin.

Thanking you.

Comment: You can do a `DYNAMIC QUERY.` Where you create a query string and you only include the required fields

Answer (score 0):

`CASE` can return only a single field (column), not multiple. I'm afraid you'll need to build two separate queries for that. I'd recommend handling this kind of logic not in SQL, but in the application code.